# How to use nifi CaptureChangeMySQL?

Tags: mysql, hadoop, apache-nifi

## Introduction

I have a mysql database that receives regular updates. I want to regularly check this mysql db for changes in Nifi.

For this, the CaptureChangeMySQL processor seems perfect.

However, I am not able to make it work.

I followed [this tutorial](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/Change-Data-Capture-CDC-with-Apache-NiFi-Part-1-of-3/ta-p/246623), but the processor does not catch anything when inserting/deleting rows from database.

---

## Setup

- One MySQL on local, accessible at localhost:3306
- One nifi on the same machine.

---

### MySQL Config

It has one database named `test` with a `device` table in it, containing a bit more than 20k rows.

My `my.cnf` file, in `/etc/mysql/` is the following:

```
#
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
#
# You can copy this to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
# 
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

#
# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
#

!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/
[mysqld]
server_id = 1
log_bin = delta
binlog_format=row
binlog_do_db = source
```

---

### Nifi CaptureChangeMySQL config

[image: config CCMySQL]

---

### Nifi CDC MapCache config (Distributed Map Cache CLient Service)

[image: DMCCS config]

---

### Nifi Distributed Map Cache Server Config

[image]

With this configuration, my CaptureChange processor just does nothing (at least nothing visible). What am I doing wrong that prevents me to use it ?

Answer (score 1):

In your `my.cnf` file, you've set `binlog_do_db = source`.

`binlog-do-db` makes the master write only statements for the specified DB into its binary log. In your case, it should be set to test.

Refer [MySQL 5.7 binlog-do-db=db_name](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#option_mysqld_binlog-do-db)